# Question about proof of chain conditions

Tags: commutative-algebra

Here is a proof from Atiyah-Macdonald:

[image]

For i) $\implies$ ii) could one not write "If $(x_n)$ is such that $x_m = x_{m+1} = \dots$ then obviously $x_m$ is a maximal element"?

I am asking because the book has been getting terser with proofs and has reached super-terse by now but "i) $\implies$ ii)" seems much longer than necessary. So I must be missing something.

Note: for the equivalence of these two statements we need choice (which is not mentioned in the book).

Comment: How could one roughly 30 word-long sentence be "much longer than necessary"? ^^

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Well : ) My suggestion is shorter, no?

Comment: But probably wrong because the authors would not write something that isn't of minimal length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that the countability issue is something of a red herring.

$\Sigma$ is a **partially ordered set**, and $T$ is a nonempty subset of $\Sigma$.  Even if $T$ is countable, it need not be an increasing chain, i.e., of the form $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \ldots \leq x_n \leq \ldots$.  So if an increasing chain $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $T$ stabilizes then the eventual value of the sequence is a maximal element of *the subset* $\{ x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of $T$, which need not be a maximal element of $T$ itself.  Thus the "longer" proof given is necessary.

**Added**: For my take on the result in question, see Lemma 10 of [these notes on factorization](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/factorization2010.pdf).  (This seems to be currently missing from my commutative algebra notes, which only mostly include the material in this shorter set of notes.)  To my eye what I say is the same as what Atiyah-Macdonald say, but someone learning the material for the first time might (possibly) think otherwise.

Comment: This is a good point. I don't have a copy of A-M handy, but I assume you are correct that $\Sigma$ is a poset.

Comment: @Alex: well, for that matter, what I'm saying holds even for countable linearly ordered sets.  For instance $\mathbb{Q}$ is such a thing but cannot be written as an increasing chain.

Comment: Thank you Pete, for this enlightening answer. Would you mind showing an example of $T$ with an increasing chain such that the upper bound of the chain is not a maximal element in $T$? I'm having trouble visualising this case.

Comment: @Clark: For instance take $T = \mathbb{Z}$ with the usual ordering, and take $x_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I somehow assumed that we have $x_n \neq x_m$ for $n \neq m$. That breaks constant sequences. If one assumes that sequences have to be "proper" (in this sense), then we'd have that every upper bound of every chain in $T$ is maximal, no?

Comment: @Clark: I thought we were working under the condition that every chain was eventually constant.  If you don't want that hypothesis, take for instance $T = \mathbb{Q}$ and $x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\Sigma$ is not countable, then not every subset $T$ is the set of terms of some sequence $(x_n)$.

Comment: $\Sigma$ is not implicitly assumed to be countable? Writing $x_n$ for elements in it makes me think that it is.

Comment: Of course if the answer is no then your answer answers  my question wonderfully.

Comment: The whole set is note denoted $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ though, is it? I talk about elements $x_n\in\mathbb R$ all the time, and $\mathbb R$ is not countable.

Comment: True : ) ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion is coming from the fact that $\Sigma$ *a priori* is any set that we don't know is countable or not - how on earth does not get a "sequence" out of this to contradict the ACC say in a proof? Perhaps the proof of (1) $\implies$ (2) from Isaacs' *Algebra* may be more illuminating:

Suppose $\Sigma$ satisfies the ACC and that there exists $S \subseteq \Sigma$ not empty such that $S$ has no maximal element. Then for every $a \in S$, the set

$$\{b\in S : b > a\}$$

is not empty. Now we invoke the axiom of choice: given any $a \in S$ I can always choose $b$ such that $b > a$. Viz, there exists a "choice function" $f : S \rightarrow S$ such that $f(a) > a$ for all $a$. Now choose just some $a \in S$ and set $a_1 = a$,  $a_2 = f(a_1)$, in general we have $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$. Then

$$a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \ldots $$

is an increasing sequence that does not stabilise, contradicting the ACC.

Comment: Thank you, good idea to mentioned that we invoke choice.